# How to get the focal length from the homography if the camera undergoes translation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, panoramas, image-stitching, 360-panorama

The image stitching from OpenCV is based on the assumption that the camera undergoes rotation around its center only.
Under the condition, the transform between two images can be expressed by
one homography. The focal length can be obtained from the homography.
The parameter focal length is required for cylindrical projection and spherical projection.

For mobile phone users, it is difficult to ensure the condition.
For 360-degree panoramas, the translation of the camera is necessity.
Under this, the scene is assumed to be plat and the homography can describe the transform.
How can I get the focal length from the homography?